# Postgres - function count

Tags: postgresql, count

Thare are two tables:

```
select "PRD_ID", "PRD_AUDIT_RD", "PRS_ID", "PRS_AUDIT_RD" from lct_products 
left outer join lct_prd_properties on "PRD_ID" = "PRS_PRD_ID"
where "PRD_AUDIT_RD" is null
```

Result:

```
 "PRD_ID", "PRD_AUDIT_RD", "PRS_ID", "PRS_AUDIT_RD"
 18;"";57;"2014-09-15 22:48:37.39"
 18;"";60;"2014-09-16 17:40:32.016"
 18;"";71;"2014-09-19 22:00:31.289"
 18;"";72;"2014-10-16 23:35:50.125"
 18;"";58;"2014-10-17 11:23:51.643"
 11;"";83;"2014-12-02 13:41:19.503"
 11;"";82;"2014-12-02 13:42:09.677"
 18;"";59;"2014-12-02 13:44:23.22"
 14;"";85;"2014-12-02 13:53:00.428"
 14;"";84;"2014-12-02 13:58:12.492"
 14;"";87;"2014-12-02 14:09:21.304"
 14;"";86;"2014-12-02 14:15:15.236"
 25;"";;""
 17;"";;""
 37;"";;""
 28;"";;""
 30;"";;""
 16;"";;""
 36;"";;""
 35;"";;""
```

I need to list all product id's and count number of properties assigned to each of them. Date in column PRS_AUDIT_RD infroms that propery assigned previously to particular product was logicaly removed. So in case of product with ID=18, I want to have it also on the list with information that 0 properties are currently assigned to it.

Query below does not solve a problem beacause it does not take into account column PRS_AUDIT_RD:

```
select "PRD_ID", count("PRS_ID")  from (
   select "PRD_ID", "PRD_AUDIT_RD", "PRS_ID", "PRS_AUDIT_RD" from lct_products 
   left outer join lct_prd_properties on "PRD_ID" = "PRS_PRD_ID"
   where "PRD_AUDIT_RD" is null
) xx group by "PRD_ID"
```

but if I add condition on PRS_AUDIT_RD, I will not get product with ID=18 listed:

```
select "PRD_ID", count("PRS_ID")  from (
    select "PRD_ID", "PRD_AUDIT_RD", "PRS_ID", "PRS_AUDIT_RD" from lct_products 
    left outer join lct_prd_properties on "PRD_ID" = "PRS_PRD_ID"
    where "PRD_AUDIT_RD" is null
    and "PRS_AUDIT_RD" is null
) xx group by "PRD_ID"
```

Do you have an idea how it can be done?

Regards
Michal

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `PRS_AUDIT_RD IS NULL` clause in the joining condition, in order to keep it a `LEFT JOIN`, thus returning `ID=18` as well.

```
SELECT
  p.PRD_ID,
  p.PRD_AUDIT_RD,
  COUNT(pp.*)
FROM
  lct_products p LEFT JOIN lct_prd_properties pp
ON
  p.PRD_ID = pp.PRS_PRD_ID AND pp.PRS_AUDIT_RD IS NULL
WHERE
  p.PRD_AUDIT_RD IS NULL
GROUP BY
  p.PRD_ID;
```